# How to Load Data into Tool Strip Combobox from Database

Tags: mysql, vb.net

Does a converted combobox from toolstrip menu cannot display data from database? I'm trying to populate my converted combobox but when i tried to use .datasource and .displaymember it doesnt show from suggested list of keywords, converted combobox doesn't seem to support Data Bindings.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I find your text a bit unclear and contradictary as for what is actually wrong and desired. Hopefully, here is what you're after.

You've already got the data as `DataSet` named `dataset`. Here, be aware, you're missing a `ValueMember`, so let's assume it's only a `DisplayMember` you're after.

All you need to do is following:

```
' ToolStripComboBox1.ComboBox.ValueMember = "ID"    ' you'd use it, if you wanted a ValueMember
ToolStripComboBox1.ComboBox.DisplayMember = "name"
ToolStripComboBox1.ComboBox.DataSource = dataset.Tables(0)
```

If you want to select pre-defined item:

```
ToolStripComboBox1.ComboBox.SelectedIndex = 3
```

If you want to get selected item:

```
Dim StrSelected as String
StrSelected = ToolStripComboBox1.ComboBox.GetItemText(ToolStripComboBox1.ComboBox.SelectedItem)
```

---

If it's `AutoComplete` source giving you problems, you probably wan't to set:

```
 ToolStripComboBox1.AutoCompleteSource = AutoCompleteSource.ListItems
```

But I get a feeling, that you're confused and you actually don't need anything related to `AutoComplete`, since you also set:

```
 ToolStripComboBox1.AutoCompleteMode = AutoCompleteMode.None
```

...which is contradicting "show from suggested list of keywords". That's why I initially thought you're actually not seeing anything in your `ComboBox`, because you didn't provided `DisplayMember` and `DataSource`.

---

If you want to include a value member, first include it into SQL query:

```
SearchQuery = "select ID,name from pis.roles"
```

Then uncomment row above with Value member and it will be loaded (with no visible effect).

Comment: forget the code i'm using right now because it's for my searchbox / textbox, what i mean for "doesn't show suggested list of keywords" is that when i'm trying to use .displaymember it gives error.

Comment: 'displaymember' is not a member of 'System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripComboBox'.

Comment: i know your answer will work if its the regular combobox i'm using, but it's not, it seems converted combobox from toolstrip menu doesn't support data bindings from database.

Comment: Nope, you didn't pay attention to my code! It is not for what you call "regular" `ComboBox`. Notice, that in my code, there's extra ".ComboBox" in the code! So you don't access it like `ToolStripComboBox1.DisplayMember`, but `ToolStripComboBox1.ComboBox.DisplayMember`. Same with `DataSource` property. It's a `ComboBox` enveloped inside `ToolStripComboBox`. That's the trick you're missing, I believe. Try it :-)

Comment: Also, it's good to point out that the `AutoCompleteSource` is there in both variants: `ToolStripComboBox1.AutoCompleteSource` and  `ToolStripComboBox1.ComboBox.AutoCompleteSource`. Now honestly, I'm not sure if there's a difference and which one is correct, as I always (when needed) set `AutoComplete` via GUI, where it takes like two clicks...

Comment: ohhhh   okayyy